# Rewrite URL-string with String.replace in Actionscript 3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, string

I'm getting a string that looks like this from a database: **~\Uploads\Tree.jpg**
And I would like to change it in Actionscript3 to **Uploads/Tree.jpg**

Any idea how I can do this in neat way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `path` is the string from the database, you can use this:

```
var newPath:String = path.replace(new RegExp("^~\\\\", "g"), "").replace(new RegExp("\\\\", "g"), "/")
```

If you always have the "~\" in the beginning, you can optimize it by using `String.substring()` instead. And if you are gonna convert many strings at once, make a reference to the regex and use that instead, so you do not create a new regex for each string.